# length of a 2-D char array in a function

Tags: c++, c

This is a small code snippet. In the function g(), is there any way to know the number of strings in a[] i.e., in this case is 4.

In main I can get this with the help of sizeof() function, but since I am passing address to the function `g()` and my pc is of 64 bit that is sizeof(a) inside g() is 8 which the size of pointer, but I have to know the number of strings.

```
void g(char *a[])
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
}
int main()
{
    char *a[]={"1","2","3","4"};
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
    g(a);
}
```

Comment: Pick a language. Yes you can do it for fixed arrays in C++ by non-type parameter deduction with `g` as a template, no there is no way to do it in C without passing the length.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, BTW, it's an operator

Answer (score 2):

There are many very similar questions on SO already, that explain what arrays are, how they are passed to functions, and what the implications are. [This one, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187738/sizeof-applied-to-array-types/28188272#28188272) should provide you with enough information to work this one out... still:

You can't do that, not reliably anyway. Once an array is passed to a function, it decays into a pointer (the size of which is 8 on a 64bit platform, 4 on 32 bit). Your function argument `char *a[]` is what's known as an incomplete type. It specifies an array of pointer, but that array is of an unspecified length. What you *could* do is complete the type:

```
void g(char *a[4])
{}
```

In which case, your code will work, but that's a tad dangerous, because the function might be called with an array of a different length.

What is more common is to require a second argument to be passed (generally of `size_t`) which specifies the length of the array that is passed:

```
void g(char *a[], size_t arr_len)
{}
```

This function is to be called like so:

```
g(an_array, sizeof an_array/ sizeof *an_array);
```

Where `an_array` is, of course, an array, and `sizeof an_array` is its size in bytes, divided by the size of the type of the values within the array. `sizeof *an_array` is an alternative way of writing `sizeof an_array[0]`. It also relies on the fact that arrays decay into pointers most of the time, and since the C standard specifies `array[0]` as being the same as `*(array + 0)`, they are interchangeable...

Just a nit-pick: you might want to change this:

```
char *a[]={"1","2","3","4"};
```

To what you're actually declaring and initializing here:

```
const char *a[]={"1","2","3","4"};
```

The `char *` in `a` are constant, they cannot be altered as they reside in read-only memory, it'd be better to *either* allocate the memory yourself, or write

```
char a[][] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

Which copies the string into RW memory

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Actually I am solving a online going contest which I have solved the main part of the question excluding this part, `http://www.techgig.com/codegladiators/openparticipation/dashboard` easy level. I dont know now what to do :(

Answer (score 1):

In C, you need to either pass the size of array to the function or use a sentinel value.